# Are there prefixes which have the meaning 'originating from within', or 'originating from outside'?

Tags: prefixes

I'm looking for prefixes which mean that something emanates/flows/comes from inside / outside, as opposed to existing / being located inside' ('endo-'), or 'existing / being located outside' ('exo-').

Thanks.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the propositions that express loocaton also express motion to or from that location, so to get the sense your looking for, the prefix has to be affixed to something already (endogenous, for example).

Comment: ***endo-***: 
word-forming element meaning "inside, within, internal," comb. form of Greek endon "in, within," literally "in the house of," .  ***exo-***
word-forming element meaning "outer, outside, outer part" used from mid-19c. in scientific words (such as exoskeleton), from Greek exo "outside," related to ex "out of" (see ex-). *endogenous, exogenous*

Comment: 'Endo-' it is then.  Of for my purposes 'gen-' kind of fits the bill.

Comment: Root-word GEN (genus) meaning *Race & Kind of*. http://www.english-for-students.com/gen.html

Comment: @Josh61  Yes, 'gen-' is also medical prefix though, coming from Greek 'to produce', which as I say, kind of fits for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

**extra-**
prefix: extra-
outside; beyond.
"extracellular"
beyond the scope of.
"extracurricular"

**intra-**
prefix
(added to adjectives) on the inside; within.
"intramural"

Comment: I'm not sure this is complete, though, we may need a suffix with this. "Extraterrestrial" comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

ex- out of, from, away from.

http://www.medilexicon.com/medicaldictionary.php?t=30824

Example: 
excementosis

Reference for existing use in med-term:

http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/excementosis